# Silverlight 5 serializationInfo

Tags: serialization, silverlight-5.0

For a few months now I have been developing a Silverlight app that I would like to use the EPOC.

```
public EmoEngineException(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
: base(info, context) { }
```

The above function is giving me troubles and was wondering if any one had any ideas of how to get around the following errors:

> Error 2 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo' is inaccessible due to its protection level
>
> Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo' is less accessible than method 'Cog2.Emotiv.EmoEngineException.EmoEngineException(System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)'

I am working with elevated permissions for Silverlight and have now made this a Silverlight 5 projects as this should allow for `p/invoke`.
My guess is that I have to create my own function or class to solve this issue.
Problem is I have never used serialization, that said I am reading up on it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Convention for exception serialization in .NET is to mark the serialization constructor 'protected', rather than 'public'.

Changing the access modifier should fix your problem.